# Reactjs: Import Sidebar Component to a different page

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-bootstrap, sidebar

I have no experience with react, and I'm trying to teach myself by doing/building. I would like to add a sidebar to a page on my site. However, all my research has lead to articles and tutorials that adds the sidebar to the homepage. I don't want it on the homepage, just one page. The look and feel i'm going for is [Strip API documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/api) page:

[image]

If i could just get the sidebar on the page, then I can try to style it up the way I like. Below are my files.

component Sidebar.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import '../Styles/sidebar.css'


class Sidebar extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <div className="sidebar">
            <h1> I'm the sidebar</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default Sidebar;
```

The page I want to put the sidebar on "Developer.js":

```
import React from 'react';
import Sidebar from './components/Sidebar' 
import './Styles/sidebar.css'


export const Developers = () => (
    <div>
        <Sidebar />
        <h1> Documentation </h1>
    <div>

export default Developers;
```

My take at sidebar.css:

```
.sidebar-container{
    min-height: 100vh;
    background-color: lightgray;
  }
  .sidebar {
    width: 200px;
    padding-top: 25px;
  }

  .sidebar-link{
    padding: 10px;
  }

  .sidebar-link:hover{
    border-right: 5px solid dimgray;
    background-color: gainsboro;
  }
```

app.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Home } from './Home';
import { Developers } from './Developers';
import { NoMatch } from './NoMatch';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <NavigationBar />
        <Layout>
          <Router>
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path = "/" component={Home} />
              <Route path="/developers" component = {Developers} />
              <Route component={NoMatch} /> 
            </Switch>
          </Router>
        </Layout>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}


export default App;
```

With the added css file, `I'm the sidebar` just shows up right above `Documentation`

It's not in the "sidebar", what am i missing?

Comment: This is confusing, in Developer.js, you import Sidebar and you also create a class named Sidebar. And your class Sidebar is rendering Sidebar !

Comment: I know it is, because I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do in order to import the sidebar into the developer page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, to start with your components are configured incorrectly. It's very easy to fix it. Let's start with the `sidebar.js`.

```
//sidebar.js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import './style.css'
export default class Sidebar extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="sidebar-container">
        <div className="sidebar">
          <a className="sidebar-link">Link</a>
          <a className="sidebar-link">Link</a>
          <a className="sidebar-link">Link</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

```
//Developer.js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Sidebar from "./Sidebar";

class Developer extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
        <Sidebar />
        <h1>Developer Page</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Developer;
```

And also, in your `App.js` file, you are importing as named components. That is the reason why you are not getting the desired output. If you're importing named components you will have to export them the same way too. Currently, you are exporting as them as default, so you don't need the curly braces while importing them.

```
//App.js
import  Home  from './Home';
import  Developers  from './Developer';
import  NoMatch  from './NoMatch';
```

Update: Import this file inside your `sidebar.js` like `import ./style.css`. I have updated the code for `sidebar.js` file. Please do check.

```
//style.css
.sidebar-container{
    min-height: 100vh;
    background-color: lightgray;
  }
  .sidebar {
    width: 200px;
    padding-top: 25px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .sidebar-link{
    padding: 10px;
  }

  .sidebar-link:hover{
    border-right: 5px solid dimgray;
    background-color: gainsboro;
  }
```

Comment: I did this, and "I am the sidebar" just shows up above the `<h1> Documentation </h1>`. What do i need to do, to make it a "sidebar"?

Comment: Well, for starters you can use `flexbox` or `grids` to style the components sort of like containers.

Comment: Another option is to use UI frameworks like Bootstrap and Semantic UI which already has sidebar components out of the box for React. [Semantic UI for React](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/sidebar/).

Comment: I edited my post to reflect the css. Its still not showing up on the side

Comment: Did you import the `CSS` file inside `sidebar.js` ?

Comment: I have updated `CSS` file and `developer.js` file. Please do check. Now it should look like a sidebar.

Comment: I'm getting the following error `./src/App.js` `Attempted import error: 'Developers' is not exported from './Developers'.`

Comment: There's a typo in your import. Do it like this: `import Developers from "./Developer"` in your `App.js`.

Comment: i don't have a .Developer.js file, its .Developers.js

Comment: Alright. Then import it like this. `import Developers from "./Developers"`

Comment: It looks side bar'ish, but it screwed up the entire page layout. I'm going to work on it to get it to display right.

Comment: Yeah. I just wanted to mock a sidebar for you. `CSS` styling matters a lot. Hope you can figure that out. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your Sidebar component can be simplified to a functional component:

```
// Sidebar.js

import React from "react";

export const Sidebar = () => <div className="sidebar">I'm the sidebar!</div>;
```

Secondly, in you Developers page, you can remove the Sidebar component because you already have it and you are importing it correctly. Next, add it to your Developers component:

```
// Developers.js

import React from "react";
import { Sidebar } from "./components/Sidebar";

export const Developers = () => (
    <div>
        <Sidebar />
        <h1> Documentation </h1>
    <div>
);
```

This assumes you have the following folder structure to ensure your imports work correctly:

```
src/
   app.js
   Developers.js
   components/
      Sidebar.js
```

Comment: I did this, and "I am the sidebar" just shows up above the `<h1> Documentation </h1>`. What do i need to do, to make it a "sidebar"?

Comment: @MaxxABillion You will need to use `css` to style it as a sidebar.

Comment: I edited my post to reflect the css. its still not showing up on the side.